# Magento 2: Add product page links to header / dropdown

Tags: magento2, header, toplinks

I only have six products in my store and want to add their product page links to the main header, instead of the category page. Is it possible?

Comment: there is an option for "`Url rewrite management`' it may work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there no way to assign different page links to different menus?

Comment: yes, please search with `Url rewrite management` in google you will get lot of tutorials , for my knowledge it will work for you.